# Two approaches to a simple scattering problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

this is something that have puzzled me for some time and I couldn't figure it out. Consider the very simple first quantization $1d$ scattering problem ($\hbar=1$):

$$ H = -iv_F \partial_x + c \delta(x)$$
where a main point here is the linearized dispersion relation. This can describe for example a scattering of an edge mode in a topological insulator off an impurity. We'll solve it in two ways.

## approach 1

A direct solution to the eigenproblem $\left[-iv_F\partial_x + c\delta(x)\right]\psi(x)=v_F k \psi(x)$. We have
$$ -iv_F\frac{d\psi}{\psi} = \left[v_Fk + c\delta(x)\right]dx$$
and by integrating we have
$$\psi(x) = e^{i\frac{c}{v_F}\theta(x)}e^{ikx}$$
up to a normalization factor. We get the scattering phase $c/v_F$.

## approach 2

we write an Ansatz $\psi(x) = \left[\theta(-x) + T \theta(x)\right]e^{ikx}$ and by integrating an infinitesimal about $0$ $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}H\psi(x) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}v_F k \psi(x)$$ one gets
$$ iv_F \psi(x=-\epsilon) - iv_F\psi(x=\epsilon) + c\psi(0) = 0$$
we need to decide what is $\psi(0)$ and we *choose* $\theta(0)=1/2$ to get
$$ iv_F(1-T) = -\frac{c}{2}(1+T)$$
which gives
$$\frac{1-T}{1+T} = -i\frac{c}{2v_F}$$
for $T=\exp\left[2i \tan^{-1}(c/2v_F)\right]$ so the scattering phase is $2i\tan^{-1}(c/2v_F)$ which is different than the previously found one.

## discussion and question

while the first approach is more direct, and the second one was done via an ansatz and an assumption on $\theta(0)$, I "like" the second result more. It makes no sense for $c$ to have unique values such that $c=0$ and $c=2\pi n v_F$ result in the same answer. Why the multiples of $\pi$? The second result is physically appealing, with $c\to \pm \infty$ resulting in scattering phase of $\pm \pi$, and an interpolation between.

The different results can also lead to physically meaningful different quantities. If we place everything on a line of length $L$ and enforce periodic boundary conditions, we get different quantization for the values of $k$ as $k_n L + \varphi = 2\pi n$ with $\varphi$ the scattering phase.

So which approach is the correct one (if any) and what is the source of the difference? I have a feeling that it has something to do with the linearized spectrum but I am really not sure about it.

Comment: what earned me the downvote? i am open to suggestions for improvements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method is the correct one. When in doubt, it’s best to revert to approximations of unity. I will use the usual one where I replace delta by:
$$
\delta_\epsilon(x)=\frac{f(x/\epsilon)}{\epsilon}
$$
A usual choice is $f=\text{rect}$ the indicator function of the interval $(-1/2,1/2)$. But any $f$ of integral $1$ will do.

Up to a change of timescale, I'll set $v_F=1$. In this case, your first method still works:
$$
\psi(x) \propto \exp\left(ikx-ic\int_{-\infty}^x ds \delta_\epsilon(s)\right)
$$

As $\epsilon\to 0$ this gives your first result, and the phase shift is exactly $-c$.

If you try to apply the second reasoning on this case, you'll find the problem. To make things easier, I'll assume $f$ to be supported in $(-1,1)$. You can again integrate over $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ your formula is still correct as $\epsilon\to 0$, except for the $c\psi(0)$ term. It is your choice of $\theta(0)=1/2$ which is problematic. You essentially impose:
$$
\frac{\psi(-\epsilon)+\psi(\epsilon)}{2} =  \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \delta_\epsilon(x)\psi(x)
$$
But this is not true as you can check from the explicit formula. Form your perspective, $\theta(0)$ implicitly depends on $\psi$, so not only is the method wrong, but even when corrected does not provide resolution of the problem.

Hope this helps.